# How to get the Javascript equivalent of GameMaker's `hspeed` and `vspeed` given only `direction` and `speed`?

Tags: javascript, game-maker, trigonometry

I'm using a NodeJS server to control NPC movement in a multiplayer game, and when they get too close to the edge of the room I need to reverse either the horizontal or vertical components of their velocities (how to decide which, is a bridge I'll cross when I get there).

The problem is I already have their `direction` and `speed`, and am able to convert it to `hspeed` and `vspeed`, but not back again.

I need the inverse of this function:

```
function velocityToSpeeds(direction, speed) {
  return {
    x: -speed*Math.sin(Math.toRad(direction - 90)), 
    y: -speed*Math.cos(Math.toRad(direction - 90))
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You want to convert cartesian coordinates to polar.

Use [`Math.atan2(vy, vx)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) to get direction (it's in radians).
For velocity magnitude, use `Math.sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy)`.

`vx` and `vy` are your horizontal and vertical components of speed.

#### Also

Your existing code can be simplified.

```
function velocityToSpeeds(direction, speed) {
  return {
    x: speed*Math.cos(Math.toRad(direction)), 
    y: speed*Math.sin(Math.toRad(direction))
  };
}
```

Comment: I intend to give you best answer, I just want to test it first.

Comment: @CocoDaWhiteBerry did it work?

Comment: I got it to work with some modifications, which I've posted as my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with these formulas:

```
function velocityToSpeeds(direction, speed) {
  return {
    hspeed: Number(-Number(speed)*Math.sin(Math.toRad(Number(direction) - 90))) + 0, 
    vspeed: Number(-Number(speed)*Math.cos(Math.toRad(Number(direction) - 90))) + 0
  };
}

function speedsToVelocity(hspeed, vspeed) {
  return {
    direction: Math.round(Number(Math.toDeg(Math.atan2(Number(vspeed), Number(hspeed))))) + 0,
    speed: Math.round(Number(Math.sqrt(Number(hspeed) * Number(hspeed) + Number(vspeed) * Number(vspeed)))) + 0
  }
}
```

Here are a couple more as a bonus:

```
function negativeHspeed(direction) {
  return ((180 - direction) + 360) % 360;
}

function negativeVspeed(direction) {
    return 360 - direction;
}
```